# How do i connect sql server which is installed on another computer

Tags: networking

Assume that I have three computers `c1`, `c2` and `c3`. I have installed SQL Server 2005 on  the `c1` computer.

Now I have a application based on ado.net and installed on `c2` and `c3`.

So how can I connect my application to `c1`'s SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), also you need to know IP-address of each computer.